# Remove text in string between two characters if previous character is a number in a text format

Tags: excel, vba

Editing the question with the code I have already tried - apologies for not posting it but because it wasn't working I thought it would only make the question more unclear.

---

I have looked at the answers to similar questions but didn't manage to edit the scripts to what I need as I think my task is a bit specific.

I have a cell containing this type of string:

```
"BAA   100 UVT  2645-2733 AAA DAYUQK/FOUR-FIVE  540K/340K CALOWB MIWOH  FDX"
```

Using VBA excel, I would like to remove "/340k" from the string above, or more exactly, all the characters after "K/" and the before the next space if the character before "K/" is a number (ie the first "K/"in "DAYUQK/FOUR" should be ignored).

I have tried editing the script below found online:

```
Public Function DELBRC(ByVal str As String) As String
  While InStr(str, "K/") > 0 And InStr(str, " ") > InStr(str, "/")
    str = Left(str, InStr(str, "K/") - 1) & Mid(str, InStr(str, " "))
  Wend
  DELBRC = Trim(str)
End Function
```

I think it doesn't work because there are already spaces in my string before "K/". I didn't get anywhere trying to use a condition IsNumeric as I don't seem to be able to identify the character before "K/" within the str variable.

I have also tried using solutions based on regular expressions but it didn't work and I haven't kept all the different scripts I tried.

If someone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated. Please be assured that I've browsed the web and tried many scripts from similar questions for half the day before asking the question here.

Thank you.

Noemie

Comment: You will definitely get help if you show/share your efforts. You will not get free code here.

Comment: Find out about `split`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cycles through the "words" tries to split them on `K/`.  Then is checks if the first value of that split is numeric and the split results in two strings.  If so, it replaces the resultant second string with `""` and returns the result.

```
Public Function delbrc(str As String) As String
Dim strarr() As String
strarr = Split(Application.Trim(str))
Dim str2 As Variant
For Each str2 In strarr
    Dim str2arr() As String
    str2arr = Split(str2, "K/")
    If UBound(str2arr) > 0 And IsNumeric(str2arr(0)) Then
        delbrc = Replace(str, "/" & str2arr(1), "")
        Exit Function
    End If
    delbrc = str
Next str2
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It took me a bit of time to understand that I need to replace the string by the result of the function (for instance if the string is in Range("A1") then I need to do: Range("A1").Value = delbrc(Range("A1").Value)
But when I finally understood the function worked great inside the loop through all rows containing strings. Thanks so much for your answer and your tolerance with my poor VBA level!

Comment: @NoemieM please mark the one that worked for you as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer that you used.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I wanted to try the solution using regular expression as well. Both solutions work very well but it seems I can't accept both answer so I've accepted the first one as a resolution though the regular expression answer worked perfectly too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done fairly easily with a regular expression.

This is the required regex and explanation.

**(\d+K)/\S+**

```
(\d+K)/\S+
```

Options: Case sensitive; ^$ don’t match at line breaks

- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(\d+K)`

  - [Match a single character that is a “digit”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
  - [Match the character “K” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `K`
- [Match the character “/” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `/`
- [Match a single character that is NOT a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\S+`

  - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`

$1

- [Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `$1`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Here is some code showing one method of implementing this as a UDF

In the example below, I used early binding.  If you don't want to set the reference, you can change it to late binding.

```
Option Explicit
 'Set Reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
Function ReSub(S, SrchFor As String, ReplWith As String, _
    Optional myGlobal As Boolean = True, _
    Optional myIgnoreCase As Boolean = False, _
    Optional myMultiline As Boolean = False) As Variant
Dim objRegExp As RegExp
Dim t(), I As Long

Set objRegExp = New RegExp
objRegExp.Pattern = SrchFor
objRegExp.IgnoreCase = myIgnoreCase
objRegExp.Global = myGlobal
objRegExp.Multiline = myMultiline

If Not IsArray(S) Then
    ReSub = objRegExp.Replace(S, ReplWith)
Else
    ReDim t(1 To S.Count)
    For I = 1 To S.Count
        t(I) = objRegExp.Replace(S(I), ReplWith)
    Next I
    ReSub = t
End If
End Function
```

**example formula**

```
=ReSub(A1,"(\d+K)/\S+","$1")
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: wow thanks a lot. Sorry for the late answer, it took me a bit of time to understand the regular expression explanations but I think I roughly get it. I had to install Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions library and then the code worked great. Thanks a lot.